# How can I add a formula field in my NetSuiite saved search to show me where the invoice date is equal to the due date

Tags: netsuite, saved-searches

How can I add a formula field in my NetSuite saved search to show me where the invoice date is equal to the due date. I only want to see these records as they would be wrong.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a Formula (Numeric) criteria column with the formula `{duedate} - {trandate}` and check if it is equal to 0

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use formula as, 
CASE  WHEN {trandate} = {duedate} THEN 1 else 0 END

as indicated in snapshot:

[image]